# Convert doc into pdf

Tags: java, openoffice-base

I want to convert word doc into pdf format. I have a cloud base server of java.
But problem is I can't install openoffice on it. Can I have any other option to do so. or can I use OpenOffice API without install open office on server.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437394/java-library-for-converting-word-documents-to-pdfs-or-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I have any other option to do so. or can I use OpenOffice API without install open office on server?

---> YES, [OpenOffice.org](http://www.openoffice.org/api/) offers a language independent application programming interface (API) which allows to program the office in different programming languages (e.g. C++, Java, Python, CLI, StarBasic, JavaScript, OLE). It allows to use OpenOffice.org as service provider in other applications, extend it with new functionality or simply customize and control OpenOffice.org.

Answer (score 0):

Not many systems can do doc->pdf.  Since you have installation limitations you probably need to use a service on the net.  If you want to simply convert documents look at something like [Convert.Files](http://www.convertfiles.com).  [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) has a cloud-service that can help if you want to generate PDFs from Doc with data merging.  You don't need to install anything but you do have to sign up.  It is unlikely that the accepted answer is going to help you reach an OpenOffice install without a lot of work.